# How to use data validation with ReactiveObject as a base class of my viewModel

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I am trying to use IDataErrorInfo implementation in a WPF project with a viewmodel using ReactiveObject.

UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged does not seem to trigger data validation (I tried with a classic NotifyPropertyChangedBase instead of ReactiveObject and it works fine).

Possible solutions I found differ depending on versions of reactiveUI, I am using 8.3.1 and for now none of them seemed to work. Documentation just link to a project which seems to do a complete implementation of validation which has a lot of dependencies and is not properly licensed, I don't think I can use that.

Is there a standard way to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface and raise the `ErrorsChanged` event whenever you want to trigger the validation:

```
if (ErrorsChanged != null)
    ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("PropertyName"));
```

Please refer to the following MSDN article for more information and an example.

[WPF 4.5: Validating Data in Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx)